# Using ArcPy to write feature class name to field in GDB?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I have a file GDB living in a network directory with 17 or 18 feature classes.  I already created a field I want to populate with the file name of the feature class.  Whenever I run my code, it returns

> NameError: name 'Washington_PETA' is not defined

This is presumably the first feature class it finds in the GDB.  File path altered because there may be sensitive data in it.

Doing this in Python 3 because we're using ArcGIS Pro.

```
import arcpy, os, sys

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"R:\filePathHere\feature.gdb"

petas = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in petas:
    print("Updating " + fc)

    inField = "PETA_Name"
    fileName = os.path.basename(fc)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, inField, fileName, "PYTHON3")

    print(fc + " completed")
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user, please be sure to take the short [tour] to learn about this site's focused Q&A format.

Comment: You dont need to use `os.path.basename(fc)` since fc will be the name of a feature class without the path, so fileName=fc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Field Calculator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm) expects a quoted string in its expression parameter if you are supplying a simple text string. You can concatenate a pair of double quotes like so: `'"' + fileName + '"'`.

Your full script would be:

```
import arcpy, os, sys

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"R:\filePathHere\feature.gdb"

petas = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in petas:
    print("Updating " + fc)

    inField = "PETA_Name"
    fileName = os.path.basename(fc)
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, inField, '"' + fileName + '"', "PYTHON3")

    print(fc + " completed")
```

Comment: Or `"'{0}'".format(fileName)`